# java.lang.ClassCastException: when register Listener in android

Tags: android

This is my interface

```
interface R2OnClickFullListener {
        fun onFullScreen(fullscreen: Boolean)
    }
```

This is my fragment

```
class Rove2LiveVideoFragment : BaseFragment()
{
    
    private lateinit var onFullScreenListener: R2OnClickFullListener
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_livevideo2, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
showBigView()
    }


 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (activity is OnFullScreenListener) {
            onFullScreenListener = activity as R2OnClickFullListener
        } else {
            throw ClassCastException(
                activity.toString()
                        + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener"
            )
        }
    }

    private fun showBigView(){
     onFullScreenListener.onFullScreen(true)
    }

    }
```

This is my activity

```
class Rove2MainActivity : BaseActivity(),R2OnClickFullListener{

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        }
override fun onFullScreen(fullscreen: Boolean) {
     }

    }
```

But i am getting class cast exception  basically i am trying to pass data from fragment to activity so on attach fragment  i am registering callback please help what i am doing wrong why the class cast exception is coming

below is error

> Process: com.rovedashcam.android, PID: 31327
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.rove2dashcam.main.home.view.Rove2MainActivity@82ae1e0
> must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener
> at
> com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.rove2dashcam.main.livevideo.view.Rove2LiveVideoFragment.onAttach(Rove2LiveVideoFragment.kt:80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
    if (activity is Rove2MainActivity ) {
        onFullScreenListener = activity as R2OnClickFullListener
    } else {
        throw ClassCastException(
            activity.toString()
                    + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener"
        )
    }
```